Hypergeometric function ratio inequality
Related to a recent question (Concavity of hypergeometric function ratio), I actually only need the following inequality:
$$
\frac{{}_2\mathrm{F}_1\big(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};c+1\,;x\big)}{{}_2\mathrm{F}_1\big(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};c\,;x\big)} > 1 - \frac{x}{c}
$$
for $0 < x < 1$ and $c\ge 1$. The stronger result:
$$
\frac{{}_2\mathrm{F}_1\big(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};c+1\,;x\big)}{{}_2\mathrm{F}_1\big(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};c\,;x\big)} > 1 - \frac{x}{(2c-1)^2}
$$
would follow from concavity.
This would complete a proof that the correlation coefficient distribution with Normal predictors has monotone likelihood ratio.

One of Gauss's continued fractions for the ratio of two contiguous ${}_2F_1$
specialized to $a=b=1/2$ is
$$\dfrac{{}_2F_1(1/2,1/2;c+1;x)}{{}_2F_1(1/2,1/2;c;x)}=1-\dfrac{x/(2c)}{(4c^2+(4-2x)c+x)/(2c)-\dfrac{6xc+3x}{2c+2x+4-\dfrac{10xc+15x}{2c+4x+6-\ddots}}}$$
from which one trivially deduces that
$$\dfrac{{}_2F_1(1/2,1/2;c+1;x)}{{}_2F_1(1/2,1/2;c;x)}>1-\dfrac{x}{4c^2+c(4-2x)+x}$$
which itself is larger than $1-x/c$ when $0<x<1$ and $c\ge1$.

I was just thinking about the Gauss continued fraction. Do you have a reference for this particular one? I saw one with F(a+1,b,c+1 ; x) / F(a,b;c ; x).

Does this prove that the ratio of $1 - F(a,b;c+1;x)/F(a,b;c;x)$ has only positive series coefficients when $a\le c$, $b\le c$?

Or does is show that the series coefficients of $1-F\big(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};c+1;x\big)/F\big(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};c;x\big)$ are positive when $c\ge 1$?

I am sure it is in Cuyt et al Handbook, but in any case all these CFs can easily be obtained by using the Gauss contiguity relations, you just need to use the right one.

I tried using the basic contiguous formula
$$
F(1/2,1/2;c;x) - \frac{1-2x}{1-x}F(1/2,1/2;c+1;x) = \frac{(2c+1)^2}{4c(c+1)(1-x)} ,x,F(1/2,1/2;c+2;x)
$$
but this doesn't seem to give the CF you got, nor one with positive coefficients given the $1-2x$ term. Can you indicate any further how to derive that one (with all positive coefficients in the CF)?

In the Cuyt book, it mentions using the transformations to show that $F(a,a;c+1;x)/F(a,a;c;x) = (1-x)F(c-a+1,c-a+1;c+1;x)/F(c-a,c-a;c;x)$, which gives a continued fraction related to the Norlund fraction. But this seems different from the one you give. You have linear terms where Norlund has $x(1-x)$ terms.

Does your CF use two contiguity relations alternately?

Sorry, I am at a conference, literature not easily available. I believe I use NIST's contiguity for $c-1$, $c$, $c+1$, which I think is different from the one you give.

The formula here https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.5 is the same as the one I listed (I stated it in terms of $c$, $c+1$, and $c+2$, and divided by $c(c+1)(1-x)$. Did you possibly simplify the term that becomes $1-2x$ to $1-x$ by mistake and cancel it?
